# FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId() doesn't work offline

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to delete `FirebaseInstanceId` when user logs out. It works fine when user is online.
But it gives Exception error when user is offline. Should I schedule it for handling when user is online?

```
        FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().setAutoInitEnabled(false);
        new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                   FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().deleteInstanceId();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e("FCMERROR",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }
        }.start();
```

It throws single line Exception

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "firebaseinstallations.googleapis.com": No address associated with hostname
```

Comment: Please edit the question to show the full exception.  It might contain valuable information.

Comment: I did. Actually it is just a single line `UnknownHostException`

Comment: Looks like the app was offline at the time of the calls.  I would not expect this to be related to firebase auth at all.

Comment: Yes, this is not a Firebase related issue, but what is correct handling of deleting FirebaseInstanceId if user wants to log out and is offline?